# Catalog Input Type for Store Owner accepts numbers

Tags: magento-2.0, magento-catalog

I would like to create a new input type in Catalog Input Type for Store Owner. 
[image]

Comment: Please refer this 
https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-to-create-product-attribute-magento-2.html

Answer (score 0):

You can manage number validation for inputs default in magento 2.
You need to select "Catalog Input type for Store Owner" to Text and "Input Validation for Store Owner" to Integer number, decimal number etc.
Please check the screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Thanks. When I choose this, it accepts numbers only. But when i'm using these attributes in advanced search, it shows an empty result.
I mean, I have an attribute named capacitance, and i have given the value as 10, I'm using this attribute in advanced search, but the results are not coming.